# vertx-hk2 and vertx-jersey split package issue on intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, vert.x, hk2

I've been trying to migrate a service to java 9 and despite the fact that I can compile and run the fat.jar, I can't run it on Intellij and reason is the split package issues with the libraries vertx-hk2 and vertx.jersey since both libraries have exactly the same package ***com.englishtown.vertx.hk2***

I tried to workaround this issue with ideas like(patching-modules, excluding) but nothing seems to work an I cant just exclude one of those since both are essential for the service run.

when intellij tries to execute the service this happens

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules vertx.jersey and vertx.hk2 export package com.englishtown.vertx.hk2 to module kryo.serializers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and reason is pretty clear

So I would like to ask some help with someone had this, how did you manage to get it running?

P.S: my question to the project owner https://github.com/ef-labs/vertx-hk2/issues/8

Comment: Yeah, the "brilliance" of OSGi is now coming to the mainstream...

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to overcome the issue, I basically shaded the two jars that had the same package into one, the pom look pretty simple, something like

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- put your configurations here -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com.englishtown.vertx:vertx-hk2</include>
                                    <include>com.englishtown.vertx:vertx-jersey</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

no the ideal solution but it worked, the shaded jar merged the packages  both libraries could coexist in the same module.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, I didn't know this new constraint in Java 9.